# ASP.NET Compatibility mode in IE 9

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, ie-compatibility-mode

I have on eproblem with IE Compatibility...
for example my site in Compatibility mode which is equivalent to IE 7 has broken...
a will show you 2 screen-shoots:

1. IE 9 (normal view) - http://screencast.com/t/ysNYN3RJh
2. IE 9 (Compatibility IE 7 view) - http://screencast.com/t/7X4lR5bNyDhs

in my site i have this meta - `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`
but i think it doesn't work properly...
so, how can i fix this problem?

also i tried insert the code `<httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
        <!-- IE7 COPABILITY -->
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge" />
        <!-- IE7 COPABILITY -->
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>` in Web.config
but it also was ignored...

P.S sorry for bad English

Answer (score 0):

Your question is horrifyingly unclear.
`X-UA-Compatible` doesn't *disable* compatibility mode; it just prevents it from *defaulting* to compatibility mode.

It looks like you need an [HTML5 shiv](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/) for styling HTML5 elements in IE < 9.